# Unknown Column employee.id in on clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which is supposed to give me the details of transactions of commodities with expiry date 30 days from now.

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions T1
INNER JOIN employee T3 ON employee.id = transactions.user_id
INNER JOIN transactions T2 USING(expiry_date) WHERE T2.expiry_date >= CURDATE() AND T1.expiry_date < now() + interval 1 month
```

When I run the query,I get the following error :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'employee.id' in 'on clause'
```

How can I solve the above problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you define an alias for a table then you have to use it. You can't use the old name `employee` any more. Use always `T3` then

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions T1
INNER JOIN employee T3 ON T3.id = T1.user_id
INNER JOIN transactions T2 USING(expiry_date) 
WHERE T2.expiry_date >= CURDATE() AND T1.expiry_date < now() + interval 1 month
```

Answer (score 0):

As [juergen d said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19887521/297408), once you have explicitly defined an alias for a table, only that alias can be used to reference the table. What I would like to add is you don't seem to need to include a second instance of `transaction` into you query. The following should give you the required results:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions T1
INNER JOIN employee T3 ON employee.id = transactions.user_id
WHERE T1.expiry_date >= CURDATE() AND T1.expiry_date < now() + interval 1 month
;
```